# Pass c++ object as parameter in lua

Tags: c++, lua, components, gameobject

I'm pretty new to using lua and c++ together.  I'm creating an component based game engine where you can attach lua scripts as components to a game object (similar to unity).  I was wondering how to pass a c++ object as a parameter to lua in order to access certain variables.  Each game object has a public transform object that contains position, size and rotation.  I would like to use this relationship as so:

```
--lua script--
function init(self)
  self.transform.size = 10
end

function update(self)
  self.transform.position.x = self.transform.position.x + 3
end
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: lua does not have a C++ interface: it only has a C interface.  You will have to **extern "C"** all the calls.

Comment: https://sol2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/cxx-in-lua.html